# Large XML Response-Python

Tags: python, xml, web-scraping

I'm scraping a webpage that returns an XML response that I cannot for the life of me extract any data from. Here is my code that just returns the XML response:

```
import requests

url = 'https://www5.fdic.gov/cra/WebServices/DBService.asmx/callWS'

r = requests.post(url, data={"functionName":"SearchCRA","parmsJSON":"{\"Appl_Number\":\"\",\"Appl_Type\":\"\",\"PSTALP\":\"\",\"SUPRV_FDICDBS\":\"09\",\"BANK_NAME\":\"\"}"})

print(r.content)
```

For example I would like to extract application numbers, institution names, and application type. I'm relatively new to Python and I just can't get my head around this one.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: have you looked into the xml libraries? That should help a lot

Comment: _I cannot for the life of me extract any data from_ What have you tried?

Comment: I've tried using element tree and requests-xml and I haven't had much luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The XML response actually has a very simple structure, with just a single root element `<string>`. The text of that element contains JSON, so actually parsing the content is trivial.

Assuming you have the response in `r`, then:

```
import json
from xml.etree import ElementTree as ET

root = ET.fromstring(r.content)
data = json.loads(root.text)

for result in data['Result']:
    print(result['Appl_Number'])
    print(result['Instname'])
    print(result['Appl_Type'])
    print('--')
```

Comment: You are amazing, thank you so much. Would you mind explaining why the 'root' element is necessary? I'm not that familiar with any of this and I would love to learn more about it. Thanks again!

Comment: The content of the response is just XML text. So we use `ET.fromstring()` to parse that text and turn it into an in-memory XML representation. `ET.fromstring()` hands back the top level element (root element) of that in-memory XML representation (an `Element` instance representing the `<string>` element). Once we have that, we can easily access that element's own nested text - which turns out is in JSON format. Since parsing JSON is trivial with Python's `json` library, it's downhill from then on.